# Reducing Font File Size

Tags: fonts

Let's say I want to use the [DejaVu font](http://dejavu-fonts.org). The font files are quite large. I noticed that they seem to have lots of extra stuff that I'll probably never need. How can I go about getting them much smaller?

Comment: @Otaku. Not necessarily, although that would be nice

Comment: you can ask over at superuser.com then.

Comment: @Otaku But I'm asking this because I want to include it/use it in a program that I'm creating.

Comment: it's kind of the same as saying "how do i resize a jpg in mspaint because i want to use it in an app?" if you're doing it programmatically and you've started down that route, SO is the place to ask. if your doing it by way of an existing application or service, SU is the place to ask.

Comment: @Otaku I suppose you do have a point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the program [Font Forge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net) to open the font and remove excess symbols that you'll never use and then re-export the font, although, unless you're embedding the font in another file (like in a SWF), the size of the font file shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Yep I plan on embedding it an android app

Answer (score 4):

They don't have DejaVu, but with [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/), you can limit the character set like:

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=FontName&text=Lorem%20Ipsum
```

To satisfy @Otaku, programmatically generate and URL-encode the list of characters :)