# Font taking too much time to load on my shared web server

Tags: html, css

I am using a font on my website which is not install on my shared web server.

But now font is taking too much time to load on web server.

Following is the css that I am using.

**CSS**

```
@font-face { 
 font-family: "PT Sans"; 
 src: url(http://mysite.com/font/PTS55F.ttf); 
}

body{ font-family: "PT Sans"; }
```

Is there any other alternative to this, so the font will not take much time.

Also what to do to make font look smooth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would host the font on your own site, right now your code has to go off to another server to get the font. It will be quicker if it is on the same server.

As for smoothing the font, this might help:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspfontsmooth.htm

As per comments, the font file is too big - check out this:

[Reducing Font File Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876918/reducing-font-file-size)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes font is on a server where site is hosted. still taking much time. than it was taking earlier with local fonts.

Comment: that is really really big. I think you should look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876918/reducing-font-file-size

Comment: Hosting the font on the same server won't make a difference, if anything it's another request to the same domain (versus splitting requests across domains). But the most important thing by far is file size.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the google web fonts version of PT Sans, available here:

http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:PT+Sans

The advantage of using google's solution is that if someone visits your site and they have previously visited another site using the same font, they will likely have the font files cached and will not have to download the files in use by your site. If you host the font files on your server, the same user with the font cached from google will have to re-download what is effectively a duplicate.

The other obvious bonus is that it saves your server's bandwidth!