# Asian Characters Performance Issues in Flex Application

Tags: flex4

We are embedding Arial Unicode Font (limited range only) within our flex application to support English, Japanese, Chinese & Korean languages, earlier We were using Verdana system font for english, We are observing some application slowness while entering/displaying the non-english characters, I am not sure if it's really because of our above mentioned css changes or something else, Is anyone aware of any kind of limition with regards to application performance for the embedded fonts within Flex Application (MX Components).

Please advise/suggest.
Please also do advise if anyone is aware of any lightweight font file that can support English, Japanese, Chinese & Korean languages only.

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: You may want to look into [reducing font file size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5876918/264541) or maybe [remove some glyphs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635423/way-to-reduce-size-of-ttf-fonts).